# combining regression model estimates into a single table

Tags: r

I am trying to automate the process by which I output the coefficients and standard errors from a number of regression models into a single table for output via xtable as html.

Some similar questions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347634/combining-several-regression-tables-into-one-for-use-in-xtable-with-sweave-in-r)) have been directed to a function called "outreg" by Paul Johnson, but the page no longer exists and I can't find the code.

Others ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669137/in-r-how-to-combine-the-summary-together)) use solutions  that seem to give me errors because my models do not all have the same number of variables.

To clarify my task ...

- I have n polr (ordinal logistic) models from which I want to output the coefficients and standard errors.
- Each model includes a different number of predictors.
- I need one data.frame (?) with a column or two for each model and a row for each predictor
- it's not critical how the standard errors are output in relation to the coefficients

each model has output like this with successively more predictors:

```
>summary(model1)["coefficients"]
$coefficients

                Value Std. Error  t value
relGPA          0.8683499 0.04185389 20.74717
mcAvgGPA        1.3885515 0.09688030 14.33265
Deny|Waitlist   0.5707912 0.01553476 36.74283
Waitlist|Accept 0.8398921 0.01618358 51.89779
```

Comment: I imagine this will be applicable here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6856/aggregating-results-from-linear-model-runs-r

Comment: Excellent, thank you Chase!  The graph suggestions on the question are pretty awesome, but the mtable{memisc} solution is exactly what I was hoping to find.

Comment: The outreg function is still available on PJ's website:          http://pj.freefaculty.org/stat/ps706/

Comment: Thanks ATMathew, I looked around his site quite a bit, but hadn't found that folder.  Good to have it linked from here because none of the other threads that mention it have the updated link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing regression coefficients from multiple models to a shared data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685806/printing-regression-coefficients-from-multiple-models-to-a-shared-data-frame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cut and paste from [here](http://ryouready.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/outreg_code_by_paul_johnson.pdf).

FWIW, I have tinkered with his `outreg.R` to add some features (t-stats, multipage, etc), but it's only on my work computer, so I'll post tomorrow.

---

Update

[Here's](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2156037/outreg.R) my tweaked version, but like the original, it still requires a list of `lm` or `glm` objects. It seems too long to cut&paste, so this is a link to my dropbox.com public folder.

Comment: thanks richardh, I'd love to take a look at your tinkered version because I'm not having luck with the code in the PDF.  I'm getting errors about the use of "$" somewhere in the function.  I think it may have to do with my models being polr().  Or I may have introduced an error transferring from the pdf.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `polr()`, but `outreg.R` requires an `lm` or `glm` object.

Comment: Thanks for contributing your version of outreg.  I'll mark this as answered since it is a good solution for people not doing ordinal logistic models.  For others that are, the mtable function in memsic is working great.

Comment: The DropBox link no longer works and the linked document has errors and seems very dated. I think this might be a good example of why code for the solution should actually be contained in the solution, not linked.

This is a good question but I recommend that the solution be deleted so that a more up to date solution can be provided.

Comment: @Hack-R -- Yes, I mentioned that the file is too long to cut and paste into the SO text field. Your best bet now is the `stargazer` package. A lot changes in 3.5 years. :)