# How do you run an R script for ML in PowerBI?

Tags: r, machine-learning, tree, powerbi, linear-regression

What is the best way to deploy a machine learning script written in R (ie. linear regression, random forest, k-means, etc.) to PowerBI?

Here is what I am currently thinking: My response column is column_x. My training set will be all rows in my dataset where I have a value for column_x. My test set will be all rows where I do not have a value for column_x (hence needing a predicted value from the ML script). I will put the output of the ML script in a new column in PowerBI (using edit queries option) for predicted response called pred_column_x. Not really sure how to go about this.

Modification/filling in of the sample script below or an alternative solution to how this could be mapped out would be super helpful!

Thank you!

```
data.df <- dataset in PowerBI

train.df <- dataset where column_x is not null??
test.df <- dataset where column_x is null??

#linear regression fit
fit <- lm(pred_column_x ~ column_a + column_b, data=train.df)
#need this fit/predicted value to go in pred_column_x
summary(fit)
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? It might be easier to run the R in SQL Server and pull the results into Power BI with your query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/quickstart-r-create-script?view=sql-server-ver15.

Comment: @ava You'll find everything you need to get going here: [Multiple Linear Regression in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796873/multiple-linear-regression-in-power-bi/48990338#48990338)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Linear Regression in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796873/multiple-linear-regression-in-power-bi)

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I was working on a contractual job, wherein the source data could only be accessed through PowerBI (PBI). The objective was to build a predictive model. I'm a novice in PBI. Since, I use R for all my analysis, I wrote a script and applied it to the data in PBI. Here are some points you must know;

1. PBI always refers the data contained within it as, `dataset`. So, change all occurrences of dataset in your R script to `dataset`.
2. In PBI interface, click on `edit queries`, then choose the table that you want to work with as shown 
   [image]
3. Then click on `Transform` tab and click on `Run R script`. A message on `Insert step` will pop up, see screenshot. 
   [image]
4. Click on `Insert` button. This will open the `Run R script` editor window. Notice, the message, `# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script` (this is what i referred to in point 1).
5. Add your `R` code in this box and click `OK` button. The code will execute and give result.

[image]

**Points to note**

1. If the dataset size is **huge**, its advisable to take a sample of it. Then execute the code on this sample on your local R environment. This will ensure the script is working without errors.
2. The predictive analytics result need to be saved in a dataframe format otherwise PBI will not show the results. So this part of your R code, `#linear regression fit
   fit <- lm(pred_column_x ~ column_a + column_b, data=train.df)`, needs to be saved as a dataframe, like, `#linear regression fit
   fit <- data.frame(lm(pred_column_x ~ column_a + column_b, data=train.df))`. Apparently the `dataframe` of R is interpreted as a `table` in PBI.
3. The analysis result will look something like this,[image] You'll have to click on the `Table` to view the result.

**Disclaimer**

If anyone got a better approach then please suggest in comments.

Comment: This is super helpful! Thank you. Another question, what if I would like the values to be in a new column in my existing dataset, instead of in its own dataframe? I'd basically like to predict a column value for each row. I wasn't able to use the dataset$value operator due to the list having fewer values than the data ("replacement has 500 rows, data has 800) Thanks!

Comment: @ava ask yourself the same question that you've asked me! If you can add the predictions as a new column in the existing dataset, in the local R environment, then it should work in PBI too...